# How to display an array of objects on the html page when using angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a json file which i will be fetching using $http service.
The sample json is added.
I am saving the json to angularjs scope variable.
How to display the dat in html.

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>English Premier League</title>

</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController">

        <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Premier League</a>
            </div>


            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Header -->
    <!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
    <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('img/soccer-bg.jpg')">

    </header>

    <div ng-repeat="blog in array">        
       <ul class "nav nav-pills">
       <li><a href ng-click ="tab"={{$index+1}}>{{blog.matches}}</a></li> 
   </ul>

</div>   
</body>

</html>
```

JSON file->

```
{"name":"English Premier League 2015/16","rounds":[{"name":"Play-Off um 1 Premierleague-Platz:","matches":[{"date":"2015-08-08","team1":{"key":"manutd","name":"Manchester United","code":"MUN"},"team2":{"key":"tottenham","name":"Tottenham Hotspur","code":"TOT"},"score1":1,"score2":0},{"date":"2015-08-08","team1":{"key":"bournemouth","name":"Bournemouth","code":"BOU"},"team2":{"key":"astonvilla","name":"Aston Villa","code":"AVL"},"score1":0,"score2":1}]},{"name":"Matchday 2","matches":[{"date":"2015-08-14","team1":{"key":"astonvilla","name":"Aston Villa","code":"AVL"},"team2":{"key":"manutd","name":"Manchester United","code":"MUN"},"score1":0,"score2":1},{"date":"2015-08-15","team1":{"key":"southampton","name":"Southampton","code":"SOU"},"team2":{"key":"everton","name":"Everton","code":"EVE"},"score1":0,"score2":3}]}]}
```

**IN the output whole array is displaying.Below is the app.js file**

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('blogApp', []); 
myApp.controller('mainController',['$http','$scope',function($http,$scope) {
      $http.get('https://xxxxx.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.array=data;
        console.log(data);
        console.log($scope.array);
      });
}]);
```

Comment: Please put some effort into making your question legible. See [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for formatting help, and [ask] for how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you need to be displaying in html page.

Instead of getting the json over http request i have hardcoded the value and made the following example.

Hope it helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {

      angular.module("blogApp", []).controller('mainController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {
          
          $scope.array = {"name":"English Premier League 2015/16","rounds":[{"name":"Play-Off um 1 Premierleague-Platz:","matches":[{"date":"2015-08-08","team1":{"key":"manutd","name":"Manchester United","code":"MUN"},"team2":{"key":"tottenham","name":"Tottenham Hotspur","code":"TOT"},"score1":1,"score2":0},{"date":"2015-08-08","team1":{"key":"bournemouth","name":"Bournemouth","code":"BOU"},"team2":{"key":"astonvilla","name":"Aston Villa","code":"AVL"},"score1":0,"score2":1}]},{"name":"Matchday 2","matches":[{"date":"2015-08-14","team1":{"key":"astonvilla","name":"Aston Villa","code":"AVL"},"team2":{"key":"manutd","name":"Manchester United","code":"MUN"},"score1":0,"score2":1},{"date":"2015-08-15","team1":{"key":"southampton","name":"Southampton","code":"SOU"},"team2":{"key":"everton","name":"Everton","code":"EVE"},"score1":0,"score2":3}]}]};
      }]);


    }());
  </script>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body ng-app="blogApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div>
      <h1>Test: {{array.name}}</h1>
      <div ng-repeat="round in array.rounds">
        <h3>Round: {{round.name}}</h3>
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Team 1</th>
              <th>Team 2</th>
              <th>Score 1</th>
              <th>Score 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="match in round.matches">
              <td>{{ match.date | date}}</td>
              <td>{{ match.team1.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ match.team2.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ match.score1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ match.score2 }}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
       
    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That worked I made it work using $http request. Thank you ... Thanks for your help..!!!!

Comment: Please vote or accept my answer. [Link to help you vote or accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)